# Spyder-IDE how to leave argument inspection open

Tags: python, ide, parameter-passing, spyder, preference

Lets say I type the following in Spyder-IDE:

```
min(
```

Spyder will then automatically open the arguments list of the function min and give me:

```
Arguments
min(iterable[, key=func])
```

I find this very helpful but Spyder closes this list after 1.5sec. I would like to have this still open after 1.5sec. In fact it would be perfect if this list remained open while I type the arguments since it helps me to see what I need to specify for a correct function call. As far as I can remember, other IDEs such as Eclipse or QtCreator support this. Is this also possible with Spyder?

In the preferences section under Editor I found:

```
Highlight occurences after 1500ms
```

Changing this value has however no effect and it seems that this is not the value which I want to change.

Comment: Not sure if the question is "off topic" as per SO rules, but would definitely like to know the answer too...

Comment: I think it's on topic, why wouldn't it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're okay with having a "side" window, what you can do is go to Tools > Preferences > Object Inspector, and check off the Editor, Python Console, and IPython Console boxes, then click Apply/OK. Then navigate to View > Panes and click Object Inspector. It should pop up as another window next to your main text window. It's not exactly inline, but it will give you the same info (plus more).

I'm not sure if you have to check off all of "Editor, Python Console, and IPython Console", but it didn't work for me when I just selected Editor for some reason...

I'm on Spyder 2.7, btw.

HTH!

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. I will leave this question open in case someone has a better solution. The object inspector is good and I can shrink its size but it would be perfect to have a solution without an extra window. But if there is no better solution I will use your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Looked for another 20 minutes now, I can't figure out how to inline it. I doubt the capability exists, and if it does, it's really unintuitive and hard to find. I suggest submitting an issue if you really want/need the capability (Help > Report issue...)

Comment: Ok there seem to be no better solutions. The credit goes to you mwm314 :-)

Comment: I find the term "check off" a bit confusing: in my case I had to switch the the boxes to ticked. I was going to edit your answer to clarify but thought I should check with you first. Anyway for me ticked boxes work, unticked boxes don't work.